# Asp.Net Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I Bind the Dropdownlist at runtime and data is populated to the database. Its ok Fine. But if i want to select the particular value and display in a message box. It only shows the default value.

Here My code is:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("You have selected " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
  }
```

So how can i display the selected value in the message box.
Here i am very new. Please help me.

Comment: 12 Questions and no answers accepted ?

Comment: Select the Checkmark/Tick against the answer you found useful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Response.Write("<script>alert('You have selected ' + '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "')</script>")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `Page_load` event, where you are assigning your `Datasource`. When you click the button, `Page_load` will be called again and it will rebind to your dropdown again.

It should be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Set your dropdown datasource here...
    }
}
```

Comment: so what was the issue finally ? which solution helped you ?

Comment: That's right every time your page will postback it'll populate the ItemList of DropDownList and set the SelectedIdex, SelectedValue, & SelectedItem to the default ones, so put the population on !PostBack aka HTTP GET

Comment: Problem was i am not using the page.ispostback, so that was the error. So now it is working fine. Thank u very much

Comment: then you accepted the wrong answer, As I mention the page.Ispostback issue. You must have to do correction in your acceptance.